# Python make iterable list which holds int from int

Tags: python, iterable

**The full story**

I have a list of namedtuples which itself holds a tuple and a string as follows:

```
a = [
     X((            1,       1), "a"),
     X((            2,       1), "b"),
     X((       [3, 4],       1), "c"),
     X((range(25, 30),       4), "d")
     X((           13, [6, 14]), "e")
    ]
```

I want to return the namedtuple by comparing the value of a given tuple to the value in the first tuple.

Eg.

```
 b = (1, 1)
 return [x for x in a if a.val == b]
```

The problem that I face is for the case `b = (3, 1)` it should return the third tuple.

I tried looking at `zip`, but that only works if the length of the iterables are the same.
I also looked at `itertools.product` but for that I need to have all elements to be iterable.

**The short question**

I'm trying to see if there's a way to iterate over the elements in the internal tuple and make it a  tuple of iterables.

Something as follows:

```
a = ([3, 4], 1)
b = [[x] for x in a]
c = product(*b)
```

The problem with this is that `[3, 4]` becomes `[[3, 4]]`. Which then results in only a single product.

I'm trying to avoid making every `int` a `list` non-programaticatlly.

Comment: So why should the `([3, 4], 1)` tuple be matched? What are the rules here? Should it be matched because the first element *contains* `3`? This sounds like a recursion problem to me.

Comment: The list implies that any of the given values should match, so `(3, 1)` should match, as well as `(4, 1)`. It's a shorthand notation for entering the values in the table.

Comment: @TsviM, should `b = (30, 6)` match `X((range(25, 30),       4), "d")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it as follows:

```
a = ([3, 4], 1)
b = ([x] if type(x) is int else x for x in a)
c = product(*b)
```

Looping over `c` returns `(3, 1)` and `(4, 1)`.

So my full code is as follows:

```
from itertools import product

def find_matching(requested):
    return [found for found in list_of_tuples if requested in product(
        *([val] if type(val) is int else val for val in found.val))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Short solution using `map()`, `any()` and `itertools.product()` functions:

```
import collections, itertools

X = collections.namedtuple('X', ['value', 'char'])
a = [
    X((1, 1), "a"),
    X((2, 1), "b"),
    X(([3, 4], 1), "c"),
    X((range(25, 30), 4), "d"),
    X((13, [6, 14]), "e")
]

f = lambda o: (o,) if not isinstance(o, collections.abc.Iterable) else o
b = (26, 4)    # searched tuple
result = [x for x in a if any(i == b for i in itertools.product(*map(f, x.value)))]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[X(value=(range(25, 30), 4), char='d')]
```